# Split em VBA não funciona

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Tenho o seguinte excerto de código:

```
CorpID = rsSQL.Fields("Name")
Tmp14 = Split(CorpID, , 1)
Tmp15 = Join(Tmp14)
Me.nomeUsuario.Caption = Tmp15
```

Onde eu quero buscar apenas o primeiro nome da pessoa, mas devolve o nome completo, ou seja a função `split` não está a funcionar, o que fiz de errado?

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `rsSQL.Fields("Name")`?

Comment: Um nome completo separado por espaços

Comment: O `split` está errado para seu propósito porque você limitou em `1` a quantidade de strings obtidas. Mesmo corrigindo o `split`, você ainda tem outro problema: está unindo novamente o nome usando o método `join`. Veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é o terceiro parâmetro.

Pela [documentação oficial do método](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx), o terceiro parâmetro é a quantidade máxima de substrings que você quer. Se não for informado, ou se for informado o valor padrão (-1), não há limite de substrings para retornar. Mas no seu caso...

Se você diz que quer no máximo uma substring, não importa quantas vezes o delimitador apareça no input. Você vai obter só uma string mesmo.

Se você quer separar em nome e sobrenome, passe no mínimo `2` no terceiro parâmetro. Isso transforma:

```
"Derpino Augusto de Oliveira Lima"
```

Em:

```
"Derpino",  "Augusto de Oliveira Lima"
```

Você pode omitir o terceiro parâmetro para quebrar a string em todos os espaços. E o valor padrão para o segundo parâmetro, que é o delimitador, é espaço (`" "`), então você pode omitir ele também. Fica assim:

```
Tmp14 = Split(CorpID)
```

Boa sorte!

Comment: Olá, exprimentei mas vai buscar o nome completo :/

Answer (score 2):

Existem dois problemas. Considerando o valor "José Roberto" em `rsSQL.Fields("Name")`:

- 1) Em `Split(CorpID, , 1)`, você limita o split em 1, de modo que acaba retornando o nome completo, "José Roberto".
- 2) Mesmo que você corrija para `Tmp14 = Split(CorpID)` de modo a retornar `Tmp14(0) = "José"` e `Tmp14(1) = "Roberto"`, na linha seguinte você os une novamente: `Tmp15 = Join(Tmp14)`. Ou seja, `Tmp15` contém novamente o nome completo "José Roberto".

O código corrigido abaixo mostrará apenas "José" em `Me.nomeUsuario.Caption`:

```
CorpID = rsSQL.Fields("Name")
Tmp14 = Split(CorpID)
'Tmp15 = Join(Tmp14)
Me.nomeUsuario.Caption = Tmp14(0)
```

Eu corrigí o `split` ignorei o `join` setando no `caption` o primeiro item do resultado do split; neste caso, "José".

Comment: Boa, essa resposta foi mais completa que a minha :)

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema, muito obrigado pelo tempo.

Comment: @SaPires Por nada!